# Using an anonymous function as part of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, anonymous-function

I'm going to show you two snippets.

This works fine:

```
this.searchBox = new Foo.UI.SearchBox(this.input, {
    autoCompleteSearchComplete: processSearchResults
});
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
this.searchBox = new Foo.UI.SearchBox(this.input, {
    autoCompleteSearchComplete: function() {
        processSearchResults
    }
});
```

I need to place that `processSearchResults` call inside an `if` statement,  to check if my search text input (`$('.search')`) has any text written inside it.

My first idea was to use this function type notation, but it's not working. It's as if the call to `processSearchResults` is never made at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you do not actually call that function. This would be correct:

```
this.searchBox = new Foo.UI.SearchBox(this.input, {
    autoCompleteSearchComplete: function() {
        if (...) {
            processSearchResults();
        }
    }
});
```